# How to know on Client in react is env prod or staging

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

How to know in react app on client, does current env is prod or staging?

On Backend / node js we have `process.env.STAGE_NAME`

But that now work on client.

This is `package.json`.

How I get that info on Client?

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd ./localDb && sls dynamodb install && cd ../",
    "buildServer": "tsc -b ./server/tsconfig.json",
    "buildClient": "next build ./client",
    "build": "npm run buildServer && npm run buildClient",
    "build:dev": "npm run buildServer && NODE_ENV=development  npm run buildClient",
    "dev": "node --inspect server/build/index.js",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server/build/index.js",
    "testClient": "nyc --reporter=html --reporter=text mocha --timeout 15000 --reporter mochawesome --exit",
    "testServer": "nyc --reporter=html --reporter=text mocha --timeout 15000 --reporter mochawesome --exit server/build/tests/*.js",
    "lintServer": "tslint 'server/**/*.ts' --quiet --project server/tsconfig.json",
    "lintClient": "eslint '**/*.{js,jsx}' --quiet",
    "lint": "npm run lintClient && npm run lintServer",
    "format": "prettier --write '**/*.{js,jsx,css,scss,ts}'",
    "test": "npm run testClient && NODE_ENV=testing npm run testServer",
    "local:db": "cd ./localDb && sls dynamodb start && dynamodb-admin"
  },
```

Comment: Are you using the same command for staging and production builds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this,

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "npm run buildServer && npm run buildClient",
    "build:dev": "npm run buildServer && NODE_ENV=development  npm run buildClient",
    "build:stage": "npm run buildServer && NODE_ENV=staging npm run buildClient",
  },
```

Now you can know the environment from **process.env.NODE_ENV**.

If you have created the app using **create-react-app** I would recommend using **.env** file. Check the link for further read, [Link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#what-other-env-files-can-be-used)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how did you run the react app and what did you define it in `package.json`

on depend on your `package.json` and `NODE_ENV=` parameter:

Start app for test env : `npm test`

Start app for prod env : `npm start`